Polar Coordinates Improper Integral
The textbook my course is using asks us to show that $I= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ given that $I^2$ is $I^2= \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$ using polar coordinates.
[Note that this is in a differential equations textbook where we covered Laplace transformations in the section the problem came from, seeing as I did not use Laplace transformations anywhere in my attempted solution I may be missing an obvious application of it.]
I keep getting that $I^2 = \pi$, which would then mean that $I = \sqrt{\pi}$ instead of $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, so I am missing  a factor somewhere in my integration.

To change to polar coordinates, I used $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. I used $dxdy=rdrd\theta$.
I rewrote the above integral in polar coordinates like so:
$$I^2= \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta$$
I evaluated the inner integral, $\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}rdr$ using the substitution $u=-r^2$, so $du = -2rdr$. Rewriting the inner integral in terms of $u$ instead of $r$, we have:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}rdr = \frac{-1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^udu$$
Taking the integral and substituting $r^2$ back in for $u$ then evaluating at the bounds of integration, we have that the inner integral evaluates to: $\frac{-1}{2} \lim_{b \to \infty} [e^{-b^2}-e^0] = \frac{-1}{2}(0 -1)=\frac{1}{2}$.
Then, the outer integral is simply: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}d\theta = \frac{1}{2}[2\pi-0]=\pi$$

Is there a mistake in my work or is there a typo perhaps in the book?

Note that if $x,y \in [0,\infty)$, then you're only working with the top-right quarter of the $xy$-plane, so you should have $\theta \in [0,\frac \pi 2]$ instead.
This will give you
$$
I^2 = \frac \pi 4
$$
in the last steps as intended.
